# Issue with network services and 127.0.1.1

Tags: networking, server, localhost

I have issues with services not attaching to the right IP and services on a small cluster of 4 servers. Right now, I have:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      un.oplo.io un
10.0.100.82    deux.oplo.io deux
10.0.100.83    trois.oplo.io trois
10.0.100.84    quatre.oplo.io quatre
```

Is it safe to replace and write:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
10.0.100.81    un.oplo.io un
10.0.100.82    deux.oplo.io deux
10.0.100.83    trois.oplo.io trois
10.0.100.84    quatre.oplo.io quatre
```

Thanks

Update:
10.0.100.81 is the valid IP of "un".

Comment: I take it that .81 is the IP of the machine you want to do the change for? If so - yes, that should be fine. You can also set up most server software to bind to a specific IP.

Comment: Yes: .81 is the IP. I tried to force the software to bind, but it looks like some of the service binds by IP and other by name and when it did a reverse, went back to 127.0.1.1. Thanks!